# Artisan Migrate ERROR

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, composer-php

I just install **Ubuntu 17.10** with **PHPstorm** and **Xammp** and i install **composer** and everything works fine `composer install` works fine but when i try to a `php artisan migrate` i get this error :

> :~/Desktop/ha$ php artisan migratePHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_curl.dll - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
>     able_schema = haabit and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>
> could not find driver `

i have tried to comment and uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll` on the php.ini from the `php/7.1/cli` folder and the `opt/lampp/etc` folder and nothing i am still getting that erorr. I also changed the password for the phpmyadmin but that didnt work either.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What is the output of `php --version`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php-curl.

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Then you need to restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Edit: also laravel needs other php [extensions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation).

Comment: I do have ` php-curl` installed. i did try it again just in case but i still get the same error. Funny thing is that i dont have this issue on my windows machine.

Comment: So you need to check other extensions.